# Is there any way to return the classname of the drop target using react-dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

Let's say I have this component, which represents a drop target.

```
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import './css/DraggableGameSlot.css';

type DraggableGameSlotProps = {
    className: string,
    text: string
}

function DraggableGameSlot(props: DraggableGameSlotProps) {        
    const [{isOver}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "image",
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        })
    }))
      
    return (
        <div className={`draggable-game-slot ${props.className}`} ref={drop}>
            <span>Drop here</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DraggableGameSlot;
```

When there is an item dropped on the div, I want to get the className of the div (console.log would be fine, I will implement the logic I want myself)

How should I modify the code to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [react-dnd useDrop documentation](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop) the `useDrop` hook returns

Return Value Array

- `[0] - Collected Props`: An object containing collected properties from the collect function. If no collectfunction is defined, an empty object is returned.
- `[1] - DropTarget Ref`: A connector function for the drop target. This must be attached to the drop-target portion of the DOM.

So, having the `DropTarget Ref` you should be able to do something like `drop.current.classList` to get the classes of the drop target html element.

Comment: I get "property current does not exist on type ConnectDropTarget"

Comment: So, what do you see when you console.log `drop`? I'm just going off the documentation, so if `drop` is the target `ref` then it should (somewhere there) have the drop target element itself...

Comment: Here's what I get: https://imgur.com/a/Xhcfd7h

Comment: But 'where' in your code are you putting your logging statement? The `ref` is undefined until the component is rendered, so it would be available within your drop event or something like a `useEffect`, but you can't just log it out right before the `return` statement of your component.

Comment: Also, I see you have put `accept: "image"` in your `useDrop` config. I'm assuming you have a `type: "image"` in your `useDrag` config?

Comment: I tried it in an useEffect already. Also in the hover event, not in the drop, but I guess it should've worked on hover too. And yes, the type is set to image in useDrag :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the underlying element from `drop` because its a function which sets other variables within react-dnd store.

I am having similar problem for a different functionality.

Only solution I have found so far is to create another ref and pass it along `drop` ref.

```
 ref: (el: HTMLElement) => {
      drop(el);
      refForHookAccess.current = el;
    },
```